# ASP.NET Dropdown list has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items

Tags: c#, asp.net

My question is very simple, i found lots of example but they are not concise and to the point.

below is the markup in my aspx file

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" DataTextField="CountryName" DataValueField="CountryCode" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

and following is the my code behind

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadCountry();
            this.ddlCountry.SelectedValue = "USA";

        }
    }

    private void LoadCountry()
    {
        DataTable dtResult = null;
        dtResult = new DataTable("Countiers");
        dtResult.Columns.Add("CountryCode");
        dtResult.Columns.Add("CountryName");

        DataRow dtRow1 = dtResult.NewRow();
        dtRow1["CountryCode"] = "PAKISTAN";
        dtRow1["CountryName"] = "PAKISTAN";
        dtResult.Rows.Add(dtRow1);

        DataRow dtRow2 = dtResult.NewRow();
        dtRow2["CountryCode"] = "INDIA";
        dtRow2["CountryName"] = "INDIA";
        dtResult.Rows.Add(dtRow2);

        DataView dv = new DataView(dtResult);
        dv.Sort = "CountryName";

        this.ddlCountry.DataSource = dv;
        this.ddlCountry.DataBind();
        this.ddlCountry.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Please Select--", "-1"));
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ddlCountry.SelectedValue = "USA";
    }
}
```

i am simply loading this drop-down with countries, during initial page load event after calling LoadCountry method i am setting selectedValue to "USA" which gives no exception or error. But after postback by clicking Button1 i am again setting selectedValue to "USA" but this time exception occurred (has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items). I understand the value "USA" is not in the list thats why it throws exception but why it didnt throws that exception initially?

Answer (score 0):

It's a documented behaviour, but I actually don't know the reason for this:

*When the selected value is not in the list of available values and a postback is performed, an ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception is thrown.*

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Theoretically, the reason is straightforward. The "selected" value maps to an index into the list of items. You can think of the items in a dropdown list as `Dictionary<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`. If the key isn't found, no index into this dictionary can be resolved. However, the value of any given item in the dictionary might, in fact, be `null`, since the items can be bound to objects (the framework simply invokes `ToString()` on them when binding). Consequently, the only safe thing to do is to throw an exception when no match can be found.

Comment: The question was "why only during post back?"

Comment: If you look at his code sample, he's preloaded the dropdown with values; there's something to match the selected value. During postback, that's likely not happening. Without seeing the markup, I can only assume that `ViewState` is not enabled for the page, or that the content of the control is somehow otherwise changed so that the selected value no longer agrees with the list of valid items.

Comment: I tried the same code as I was curios to see this behaviour. The dropdown is preloaded but the value "USA" is not present. After the post back the dropdown has still the items and the exception is thrown. So the exception is actually thrown only after a postback, as documented in the MSDN page I linked in my answer ("..and a postback is performed.."). My question was asking why the framework designers decided to throw the exception only afetr a post back?

Comment: Heh. :) I can't tell you why they decided to do anything. Algorithmically speaking, I can make an educated guess about what makes the most sense. (Well, that and I can plunder through the source code using Reflector or Resharper.) But there are plenty of places in the Framework where seemingly strange decisions were made, but once you understand the reasons behind them, you find yourself going "Ohhh... That's why." Usually, it's an edge case that's not so edge-casey as you thought it would be.